# Clarifying the usefulness of Elastic Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, couchdb

I am a bit confused about the use of `ElasticSearch`. I have an application(`Ruby on Rails`) now with a relational Database (`Mysql`) and I am trying to benefit from the search functionalities `ElasticSearch` provides. I still want to use my relational database as before, but I want to use `ElasticSearch` only for searching. Therefore, can I use ES as a secondary storage? how will tell my application to always copy data from Mysql to ES? is there any best practices here?

I have heard also that couchdb is good for searching, is it an alternative to ES or does it Provides different functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Change Data Capture in order to capture changes in MySQL, and stream those changes right to Elasticsearch using either Logstash or StreamSets (JDBC Input, Elasticsearch Output). Which version and storage engine of MySQL are you using exactly?

Regarding CouchDB - it is not a replacement for Elasticsearch or any other search oriented data stores.

Comment: Answers should not contain questions themselves, clarifying questions to help you better understand OP's problem should be comments on OP's post (I realize that you don't yet have the rep to do this, so its fine here)

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch can be used as secondary data storage.
We use Elasticsearch for searching, as it improves our search performance. (We have millions of records to search)

The approach we took :

1. Use logstash to ingest the initial data. (Database as input and Elasticsearch as output).
2. Current application is responsible to update the records in MySQL. Whenever there is an update, same update is pushed to a queue which is read by the application and used to index these changes to elasticsearch.

Make sure you use identifiable unique documentId for your elasticsearch documents. That will help in updating the records.